# How to do you find and acquire all the Pokemon Go candy colors?

Tags: pokemon-go

There are different candy colors in Pokemon Go. Where can each color be found?

Comment: Each Pokemon's candy has a set color scheme so if you want all the candies you would simply have to catch all the Pokemon.

Answer (score 12):

The candies are never referred to by their color, but instead by the Pokemon they are for which are colored respectively to match them. There is one candy for each Pokemon and all their evolutions use the same candy type. For example, there isn't a Vaporeon candy only an Eevee candy and so the candy is brown.

You get the specific Pokemon candy by catching them, evolving them, transferring them, and hatching them and any of their evolutions.

Answer (score 4):

I have not found the colors referenced anywhere yet, but you can create a candy using the following three layers.

[image]

Here is an example of masking the layers with green.

[image]

Here are the images with transparency.

[image]

---

## Update

I have compiled a list of the known primary/secondary colors for each pokemon.

```
+----+------------+--------------+----------------+----------+
| id |  pokemon   | primaryColor | secondaryColor | verified |
+----+------------+--------------+----------------+----------+
|  1 | Bulbasaur  | #36C8A4      | #A3FB83        | TRUE     |
|  2 | Charmander | #F09230      | #FFE699        | TRUE     |
|  3 | Squirtle   | #85C4D6      | #F2E8BE        | TRUE     |
|  4 | Caterpie   | #A5CD87      | #FAE3B1        | TRUE     |
|  5 | Weedle     | #E7BC83      | #DB76AD        | TRUE     |
|  6 | Pidgey     | #E9E0B7      | #D29E65        | TRUE     |
|  7 | Rattata    | #A989BA      | #D9D7BE        | TRUE     |
|  8 | Spearow    | #EBB9A0      | #FE5D6C        | TRUE     |
|  9 | Ekans      | #CBA8C9      | #F1E090        | TRUE     |
| 10 | Pikachu    | #F5D368      | #E2A65D        | TRUE     |
| 11 | Sandshrew  | #E0D2A4      | #C9B180        | TRUE     |
| 12 | Nidoran F  | #C5D3E4      | #9697C5        | TRUE     |
| 13 | Nidoran M  | #D59FC1      | #C37096        | TRUE     |
| 14 | Clefairy   | #F1D3D1      | #F1BFC0        | TRUE     |
| 15 | Vulpix     | #F5865E      | #F6D29C        | TRUE     |
| 16 | Jigglypuff | #F1D2E1      | #EAB9CE        | TRUE     |
| 17 | Zubat      | #478ABF      | #DC8DD7        | TRUE     |
| 18 | Oddish     | #7095BF      | #75C06B        | TRUE     |
| 19 | Paras      | #F1873D      | #FFD159        | TRUE     |
| 20 | Venonat    | #998FD6      | #E24379        | TRUE     |
| 21 | Diglett    | #B08570      | #EEC5DC        | TRUE     |
| 22 | Meowth     | #ECE0C4      | #FFE28A        | TRUE     |
| 23 | Psyduck    | #F4C487      | #EEEED8        | TRUE     |
| 24 | Mankey     | #E5D6CB      | #C3927F        | TRUE     |
| 25 | Growlithe  | #F3A056      | #3F3D2A        | TRUE     |
| 26 | Poliwag    | #849FCA      | #ECECF6        | TRUE     |
| 27 | Abra       | #E5CE5C      | #8E7994        | TRUE     |
| 28 | Machop     | #A1BBDE      | #DCCEB1        | TRUE     |
| 29 | Bellsprout | #EBE16E      | #AFD57E        | TRUE     |
| 30 | Tentacool  | #71ACD8      | #C24589        | TRUE     |
| 31 | Geodude    | #ACA078      | #756108        | TRUE     |
| 32 | Ponyta     | #EDE7C7      | #F59062        | TRUE     |
| 33 | Slowpoke   | #DFA1B9      | #EEE1C7        | TRUE     |
| 34 | Magnemite  | #D0DAE0      | #92B6C6        | TRUE     |
| 35 | Farfetch'd | #AC9E95      | #95FB97        | TRUE     |
| 36 | Doduo      | #C89462      | #AF755F        | TRUE     |
| 37 | Seel       | #C7DFE8      | #B6CAED        | TRUE     |
| 38 | Grimer     | #BFA4C7      | #5F5370        | TRUE     |
| 39 | Shellder   | #AB9CC5      | #E0B5B3        | TRUE     |
| 40 | Gastly     | #242223      | #9B7FB7        | TRUE     |
| 41 | Onix       | #B5B6B8      | #626264        | TRUE     |
| 42 | Drowzee    | #F8CB58      | #AF7961        | TRUE     |
| 43 | Krabby     | #EB9063      | #EDD9CE        | TRUE     |
| 44 | Voltorb    | #B64656      | #F0E5EA        | TRUE     |
| 45 | Exeggcute  | #F4DDE7      | #EFC3C1        | TRUE     |
| 46 | Cubone     | #D4D5D6      | #CBB57A        | TRUE     |
| 47 | Hitmonlee  | #BD9F88      | #EEE1C7        | TRUE     |
| 48 | Hitmonchan | #C8ABBB      | #E4643B        | TRUE     |
| 49 | Lickitung  | #E3AEB9      | #F0E4CA        | TRUE     |
| 50 | Koffing    | #8B8FAE      | #DEE0BF        | TRUE     |
| 51 | Rhyhorn    | #BCBDBF      | #959CA2        | TRUE     |
| 52 | Chansey    | #E0AEB2      | #C68D87        | TRUE     |
| 53 | Tangela    | #666C9D      | #E46E8C        | TRUE     |
| 54 | Kangaskhan | #978781      | #E3DDB8        | TRUE     |
| 55 | Horsea     | #9FCFE9      | #FCF7D7        | TRUE     |
| 56 | Goldeen    | #E6E6E7      | #F38469        | TRUE     |
| 57 | Staryu     | #B49569      | #F5E688        | TRUE     |
| 58 | Mr_Mime    | #E56387      | #FFCED5        | TRUE     |
| 59 | Scyther    | #92C587      | #F6F0CF        | TRUE     |
| 60 | Jynx       | #C44552      | #643187        | TRUE     |
| 61 | Electabuzz | #F5DB77      | #14175E        | TRUE     |
| 62 | Magmar     | #F5D477      | #F0664E        | TRUE     |
| 63 | Pinsir     | #BCB1AB      | #CFD4D8        | TRUE     |
| 64 | Tauros     | #D8A058      | #887E6F        | TRUE     |
| 65 | Magikarp   | #E87839      | #F6F0CF        | TRUE     |
| 66 | Lapras     | #6BA7D4      | #FFF0DA        | TRUE     |
| 67 | Ditto      | #AD8DBE      | #DBD8BE        | TRUE     |
| 68 | Eevee      | #CA9761      | #7E5621        | TRUE     |
| 69 | Porygon    | #E7757C      | #6BC7C5        | TRUE     |
| 70 | Omanyte    | #DDDCCC      | #73CEE2        | TRUE     |
| 71 | Kabuto     | #C18335      | #4E4E48        | TRUE     |
| 72 | Aerodactyl | #D4BAD3      | #B196C5        | TRUE     |
| 73 | Snorlax    | #326583      | #E3DACE        | TRUE     |
| 74 | Articuno   |              |                | FALSE    |
| 75 | Zapdos     |              |                | FALSE    |
| 76 | Moltres    |              |                | FALSE    |
| 77 | Dratini    | #90AED4      | #EFEAE6        | TRUE     |
| 78 | Mewtwo     |              |                | FALSE    |
| 79 | Mew        |              |                | FALSE    |
+----+------------+--------------+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how the base value is generated? I assume the game is programmed to make a histogram of the Pokémon's color value, and selects the dominant one color?

Comment: @Courtny: Not sure, but I am interested as well. I will do some more research and update this when I come up with something.

Comment: @Courtny: I created the following page to render each of the candies dynamically at page load: http://rmkane.com/experiment/pokemon/candy

Comment: Where did you get these values from? I would really like to see the algorithm used to generate them

Comment: I data-mined the base and secondary colors from screenshots of each Pokemon. My algorithm is viewable in [my script](http://rmkane.com/experiment/pokemon/candy/js/script.js).