# How many distinct colors are there across all base Pokemon? What are the colors?

Tags: pokemon-go

Related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274588/how-to-do-you-find-and-acquire-all-the-pokemon-go-candy-colors) ~ base Pokemon have distinct candy colors. What are all of these distinct base candy colors?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are asking.

Comment: There is one candy for each base Pokemon, and some have unique colors. How many and what base colors are there?

Comment: The color is really irrelevant in all of this as I explained before.

Comment: @Dom The color is not irrelevant when the question is how many and what are their colors?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what good providing this information will do.  So far as I can tell, the colors have no bearing or impact on any gameplay mechanics, so there seems to be very little need for this.

Comment: Does it need to have gameplay mechanic value? The primary reason I am asking is for design & technical purposes ~ not for gameplay advice.

Comment: @Courtny to the game play it is completely irrelevant. They could all be the same color and it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Dom I am simply curious how many colors there are and what their values happen to be! I don't need it for gameplay enhancement.

Comment: Albeit weird, this is not close worthy. The question is only unclear if you are coming at the angle of why it's relevant. At face value, it has an explicit question and answer.

Comment: Wasn't there a "this question is completely useless" close reason once?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer even if there was, there isn't now. But "not useful" is right there in the downvote tooltip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be 78 different candies. This includes Mew, Mewtwo, Ditto, and the Legendary Birds.

This number is just a count of all of the base Pokémon since the color of the candy appears to be some average of the Pokémon's color. There are no unique candies. Every Pokémon is just a different color and therefore has a different candy.

Please see: [Bulbapedia → List of Pokémon by Kanto Pokédex number](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Kanto_Pok%C3%A9dex_number)