# How many of which types of candies do I have?

Tags: pokemon-go

I hope this isn't a duplicate question; I did a quick search and couldn't find it.

If I look at a Pokémon's stats it shows me my total amount of Stardust, but it only shows the amount of Candy I have in relation to that particular Pokémon.

Is there a list somewhere that shows of which types of Candy I have and how many of each I am carrying?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no place to look at a list of all candies you own and how many of each you own. If you want to know how many candies you have for a certain evolutionary path, you must look at a Pokémon from that path (i.e. Look at a ponyta or rapidash to see how many ponyta candy you have). There is no comprehensive list for these amounts though.

Comment: Does every Pokémon have it's own type of candy (or am I just not catching the right ones)?

Comment: @boredrandom Yup. Every evolutionary chain has its own candy type. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274588/how-to-do-you-find-and-acquire-all-the-pokemon-go-candy-colors

Comment: They definitely *should* implement this though so that people know when it's a good time to pop a lucky egg. Oh, and a faster way to transfer 300 Pokemon for candies... one day.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Or if you're like me a clear out all your weak pokemon (i.e. a 10CP Poynta) yet still would like to know if you have enough candies to evolve soon.